# SSRS - Total or Summing Expressions for calculations

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a total column that needs to follow the following criteria:

If the type = 1, then it needs to total all the rows that have a '1' and then add "1 - New" at the end, if the type = 2, then it needs to total all the rows that have a '2' and then add "2 - Reprint" at the end, and if the type = 50, then it needs to total all the rows that have a '50' and then add "50 - draft" at the end.

I want to total all my New, all my Reprint, and then drafts.  I cannot find an expression that will allow me to do this.  any assistance would be great! :-)

Comment: is the type a column in your dataset? So the dataset has these three type values mixed together? If so, are you grouping on type in your table?

Comment: Yes, TYPE is a column in the dataset.  These 3 values are mixed together in the TYPE column.  I am grouping on the Selection ID, TYPE, and Status in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a row below your details row that is inside the Type group, but outside the details row. Add an expression like this one into a cell in this new row:

```
=cStr(countrows()) + iif(Fields!Type.Value = "1", " 1 - New", iif(Fields!Type.Value = "2", " 2 - Reprint", iif(Fields!Type.Value = "50", " 50 - draft", "")))
```

This expression works because when used within the Type group, the function countrows() will return the number of rows within the group, not the number of rows in the full dataset. There are other aggregate expressions you could use if you were not grouping on Type in your table.

Comment: That worked perfect!!!!  If there is more than one value say, 11 new and 8 reprints, will they stack on top of each other or do I need to add an additional field for each one?  I don't have one that does that. :-(  This was so helpful!!! Thank you! :)

Comment: The row you created should repeat for each group. After all the individual rows of Type 1, you will have the total count for Type 1, then all of the individual rows of Type 2, then the total count for Type 2, and so on. Glad to hear it is working for you, feel free to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much for your help.  I spent a day and a half trying to manipulate it and finally had to ask.  You're awesome!  Thank you.